# How to remove the first part of a path?

Tags: python, path

Say I have the path `fodler1/folder2/folder3`, and I don't know in advance the names of the folders.

How can I remove the first part of this path to get only `folder2/folder3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) with `1` as `maxsplit` argument:

```
path = "folder1/folder2/folder3"

path.split("/", 1)[1]
# 'folder2/folder3'
```

If there is no `/` in there, you might be safer with:

```
path.split("/", 1)[-1]  # pick the last of one or two tokens
```

but that depends on your desired logic in that case.
For better protability across systems, you could replace the slash `"/"` with `os.path.sep`:

```
import os

path.split(os.path.sep, 1)[1]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path) for that:

```
from pathlib import Path

p = Path("folder1/folder2/folder3")
```

And either concatenate all [`parts`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parts) except the first:

```
new_path = Path(*p.parts[1:])
```

Or create a path [`relative_to`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.relative_to) the first part:

```
new_path = p.relative_to(p.parts[0])
```

This code doesn't require specifying the path delimiter, and works for all [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) supported platforms (Python >= 3.4).